# Recursion overhead in python vs C

Tags: python, c

It is a well-known problem in python that recursion involves a lot of overhead.  So much so, that even relatively shallow recursive calls cause programs to crash.  One possible workaround would be to implement fancy recursive algorithms in C, and provide python hooks.  However, it is also well-known that a recursive implementation of an algorithm is more expensive than, say, a loop almost no matter what, unless your compiler recognizes some very specific opportunities (such as tail recursion) to loop-ify the whole business.

Anyhoo, since recursion involves the overhead of a function call, I was wondering what the relative expense of function calls (and thus recursion) is in python vs C?  I realize I could `timeit`, but I was hoping for a principled explanation.  What all goes into a python function call vs a C one?  Also, are there a difference in the function call stack between python and C that would affect performance for deep call stacks?

Comment: You want to implement recursive algorithms in C so you get a segfault instead of a nice exception when the stack overflows? =P

Comment: Any recursive process can be re-implemented using iteration; just rework your algorithm if the stack depth limits are an issue.

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's the overhead that causes recursive Python programs to crash. I reckon that's an intentional design choice. You can raise the [maximum recursion depth](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit) by a couple orders of magnitude before it causes an actual stack overflow. Or are you saying "even when setting the recursion limit very high, stack overflows occur sooner in Python than in C?"? I suppose that's true, but then it's probably true of most languages built on top of C.

Comment: recursion can always be rewritten as iterative with manual stack keeping. Python makes it very easy to implement with high-level data structures that can keep the stack.

In other words, `recursion` is just a fancy way to write iterative code and let the language manage the stacks instead of you.

Comment: the overhead time of the call is insignificant ... its the stack memory

Comment: I am not aware of recursive function calls in particular being any more expensive than any other function calls, either in Python or especially in C.

Comment: And C is going to be much, much faster. At a cost, of course, you'll have to do much more work as a programmer up front to re-implement your algorithm in C, make sure you don't overflow the C stack (Python's protection is gone there), and add the Python hooks. Once you have done this you'll find the execution speed is going to be orders of magnitude faster. You need to decide if it is worth your time to do the work.

Comment: A recursive function, compared to an iterative implementation of the same thing that makes the same number of function calls inside an inner loop, is going to be pretty close. There is a small cost to having to allocate new stack frames and get them into the cache instead of reusing old ones, but that's about the only difference. The main advantage of the iterative implementation is that if you need to optimize further, you can inline that inner function call, which you obviously can't do with recursion.

Comment: If you are rewriting it in C for performance reasons, then why do you insist on writing it recursive? The primary reason for writing recursive functions is that it makes the code clean, short and easy to read.

Comment: No amount of C can optimize away something that's fundamentally inefficient from an algorithmic design perspective. You can't make *O(n^2)* behave like *O(n)* no matter how hard you try. What problem are you trying to solve? Avoiding *premature optimization* is a constant challenge in programming. If you're blowing your stack due to too-deep recursion you're probably attacking the problem the wrong way.

Comment: @JohnBollinger points out an interesting point that the overhead of recursion in any language is GENERALLY the cost of a function call.  However, a smart C compiler will compile out the function-call-overhead of a well-written tail-recursive function.  However, I'm not a C-optimization guru, and thus the fact that this is the only such optimization known to me does not imply that it is the only such optimization.  However, I will edit the question to reflect the fact that this is essentially a function-overhead problem.

Comment: Also, @ all the comments that I should just "rewrite as a loop." 1) I pointed this exact same thing out in the question.  2) I am asking this for knowledge for knowledges' sake.  If you know the answer, please instead of saying "you don't need to know", if you were to answer the question that would be grand.  :)

Comment: Your edit makes this a pretty different question from what it originally was. Do you want me to rewrite my answer to focus on the actual cost of a function call in typical C and Python implementations instead of the higher-level question you were originally asking?

Comment: @abarnert, Your answer is wonderful.

Comment: And another question starting with something like "It is a well-known problem" (aka "as we all know") having a wrong premise. It completely depends on the platform, actual code, toolchain, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re starting from a set of faulty premises:

> It is a well-known problem in python that recursion involves a lot of overhead.

No it isn’t. The overhead for recursive function calls is essentially the same as for any other function calls. There’s probably a small difference in that you keep allocating new stack frames and loading them into the cache, whereas the same thing implemented with a loop with a non-recursive call inside would be able to reuse the same stack frame. But it’s going to be pretty minor.

> So much so, that even relatively shallow recursive calls cause programs to crash.

No they don’t. Recursion beyond a depth of 1000 cleanly fails with an exception. This is in part to prevent such crashes, but also to make it easier to detect accidental infinite recursion.

> One possible workaround would be to implement fancy recursive algorithms in C

That’s not going to help anything. Most C implementations handle recursion essentially the same way most Python implementations do (in fact. In CPython, recursion can just be a matter of C-recursing the main eval loop). There’s still no tail call elimination, no special handling for keeping only live variables from a frame alive, etc. While C stack frames are a little smaller than Python ones, this is just a small multiplicative factor.

And, meanwhile, unlike Python programs,, C programs actually *will* crash if you recurse too deeply.

---

Of course C code does tend to be an order of magnitude or two faster than Python code when what you’re doing is low-level computation, and that will help you here the same way it well anywhere else (although maybe not as much as usual, because function calls in C are, while not as slow as Python, still far from free). Plus, C does force you to be more explicit about some things—e.g., there are no closures, so if you want the effect of `nonlocal` you’ll need to pass down pointers to locals—which could lead to you optimizing things you wouldn’t think to in Python.

But in general, there is if anything less benefit here than there is in non-recursive code.

---

There are also some cases where a good C optimizer can see that the whole frame is useless and drop it. In some cases, it can even completely eliminate a tail call. This isn’t as good as universal tail call elimination that you can rely on for correctness, but it’s certainly helpful.

But a good JIT optimizer can sometimes do the same thing. And running your existing code in PyPy or Jython is certainly a lot simpler than rewriting it in C.

(I’m sure there will be some cases where, e.g., LLVM’s AOT optimizer can help but PyPy’s JIT cannot, but I also suspect that anyone who could reliably guess what those cases are wouldn’t have asked this question in the first place.)

---

There *are* languages that handle recursion better than Python and C.

If you code your algorithm in, say, Haskell, and then wrap it in a C API that you can call via `ctypes` or via a simple extension written on C (or maybe even just compile it as a program and subprocess it, if you’re talking about something that takes many seconds to run); that would work.

---

But if you instead rewrite your recursion as a loop with an explicit stack, you will eliminate all of the problems associated with using recursion in a language that wasn’t designed to encourage it (that’s both Python and C), and open the doors for other optimizations.

For example, you (or LLVM’s optimizer, or PyPy’s JIT) can inline a function call in the middle of an inner loop, which you obviously can’t do with a recursive call.

Also, it generally becomes easier to pull out pieces of your code without having to call back and forth across the Python boundary, so you can port the bottleneck to a C extension module without having to port the whole thing.

Comment: "In CPython, recursion can just be a matter of C-recursing the main eval loop" Does this just depend on the options when I compiled python, or is there some black magic happening here?

Comment: @Scott In CPython, there’s no way to get it to never use the C stack. However, it only takes some small changes to the code to do that. This is what Stackless Python (and the Stackless branch of PyPy) does.

Comment: For example, https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/VBXz0C (where clang not only found the tail call optimisation, but also unrolled the recursion by a factor of 8). GCC, ICC and MSVS all produce a simple loop (as long as the optimisation level is sufficiently high; -O2, -O1 and /O2 respectively).

Comment: @rici OK, but if your problem is "I need TCO or my algorithm is incorrect", the answer is not "I'll rewrite my Python in C and hope that many compilers can often eliminate the tail call". You either rewrite the algorithm to not need TCO, or you write it in a language that has defined guarantees for tail calling.

Comment: @abarnert: I agree. But there's a difference between saying "you cannot rely on C to optimise tail calls" and saying that there is no tail-call optimisation at all. Python does not optimise tail calls at all. But most popular C compilers do, in fact, optimise many tail calls if optimisation is enabled.

Comment: @rici *CPython* does not optimize tail calls at all. If IronPython wanted to emit CLR `.tail` calls—I actually have no idea whether it does—that would be a perfectly valid Python implementation. IIRC, PyPy's JIT goes out of its way to never eliminate tail calls, but that was an intentional decision to make it easier to generate tracebacks that are indistinguishable from CPythons, but they could easily change their minds.

Comment: @rici Anyway, I've edited the relevant paragraph to be even more wishy-washy than it was. :)

Comment: @abarnet: plus one, but just for closure: when GvR is [on record](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html) as saying "I don't want [tail-call optimisation] in Python... it's simply unpythonic", it seems to me reasonable to assume that TCO is deliberately not part of the language, as opposed to simply happening to not be done in one implementation.  :-)

Comment: @rici i’m pretty sure that if PyPy or IronPython did TCO in some cases (as long as they still generated proper tracebacks) Guido would not claim they’re no longer valid Python implementations. Even if he did, he’s a sensible guy who can be talked down (see the “non-negotiable” removal of reduce in Py3k, which was negotiated into moving it to functools). It would just be the same situation as C: code that requires TCO to be correct or reasonable would still be bad Python, even if it happens to work on one implementation with one data set, but good Python might sometimes run faster on PyPy.

Comment: Fyi: c++ proposal.  http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2018/p1063r0.pdf (see the ToC for the part about TCE). This is also a compromise; it requires the programmer to indicate when they require a tail call. (They suggest the conditionally reserved keyword `tail`, as in `tail return ...`. But IMHO it would be much more C-like to write `static return`.) Anyway, I'd be happy with that.

Comment: @rici You can't use TCE and RAII in the same function? I suppose that makes sense, but it could make for some tough design choices. (I haven't been following C++ proposals for the last few years, because I haven't been writing any serious C++ larger than a one-file Python extension, except for working on legacy code that didn't even take advantage of C++11… but this one looks interesting, so I'll read it when I get a chance.)